# Does it make sense to use multithreading for loop in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, image, list, loops

I have a list to iterate through, the first iteration took 3 minutes 40 seconds, result was a bunch of generated images being saves on hard disk. Would it make sense to split the list into 2 or 3 and apply multithreading in this case?

Comment: Yes, but you need to consider how to deal with threading.

Comment: 1) You do not need to split the list to apply multithreading. 2) It looks like this question if more about processing logic than programming, i.e. answer may vary. If you process your list once a day/week/etc... then 3.40m is not very long time. If you need to process it every 5 min, then probably yes.

Comment: You can take a look at [acyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) which is a module for asynchronous io-operations and its part of the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

You can't write to a hard disk in parallel, so using Threading/Multiprocessing wouldn't show any time improvements and would most likely add overhead.

If it's python that's slowing you down and not your disk writing speed, then it might be worth looking into the Map function, if you're using Python3.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

Otherwise you'd need to look at using a faster language like C
https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/index.html